# How to politely show "as soon as your payment is confirmed"?

Tags: payment

I'm creating a step-by-step image chart to a website describing a paid program that only liberates access when user's payment is confirmed. I want to be far from showing users some greedy icon (like a sack with a dollar sign) or limiting their idea of payment forms.

My question is: How do you politely show "as soon as your payment is confirmed"? I've thinking about bills/coins/credit card with a green check sign to say everything's right. But I've seen websites using something as simple as a green seal with a white check.

Answer (score 1):

Questions specific to images may be better directed at [Graphic Design StackExchange](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/) site

From a UX perspective using text is important, as it is less ambiguous for abstract concepts.  Also consider showing user what they would obtain (e.g. music symbol if you are selling MP3's) which would make the message more concrete, thus easier to understand.

Answer (score 1):

**Green Ticks** will work best. Not only does it look decent but, also presents a color which has a neutral effect on the minds while still showing confirmation and assurance.

[image: tick]